# Add ProgressView to Live Activity

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget

Can I add working Progress View to new Live Activities?
I'm trying to initiate timer with this code, but it doesn't work, view just sleep:

```
 @State private var progress = 100.0
    
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

```
ProgressView(value: progress, total: 100)
                    .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
                        if progress > 100 {
                            progress -= 100
                        }
                    })
```

```
 
    ProgressView(timerInterval: <#T##ClosedRange<Date>#>, label: <#T##() -> _#>, currentValueLabel: <#T##() -> _#>)
```

With timeInterval it is works, but I need to customize

Comment: Trying to do the exact same thing.. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you're not allowed to use timers to refresh your custom progress bar during live activity, or at least I didn't find a way to do so. iOS is limiting your abilities to trigger timers, loops and any logical methods to update the progress bar. The only way I found doing it is by using a native progress bar.